# Как вывести список баз данных

Tags: mysql

В консоль программы `mysql` нужно ввести такой `sql` запрос
который покажет базы данных имеющие в названии определенные символы например "_db" а не все как `SHOW DATABASES;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с вашим `_db`.

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE '_db%';
```

Или так:

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%_db%';
```

Второй пример для того если `_db` в середине имени базы данных а не в конце.

Вот [здесь](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/show-databases/) подробно все описано.

Answer (score 3):

Не каждый *statement* есть *query*.

`SHOW DATABASES` (и прочие `SHOW`) запросами **не являются**!

Одним из правильных решений (особенно если это учебно-зачётная задача) является запрос типа

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE '%_db%';
```

Answer (score 1):

SHOW DATABASES поддерживает like

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-databases.html

Answer (score 0):

SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%_db%'; Вот так нормально